# Pass target file name as compile definition in cmake

Tags: cmake

I have CMakeLists.txt with many targets and the targets have configuration-specific suffixes defined. Additionally I want to know the name of the executable inside the program.

Under MSVC++ I do this by defining

```
add_definitions("-DTARGET_FILE_NAME=\"$(TargetFileName)\"")
```

But this does not work in other generators. Now that CMake got generator expressions, is there a way that would work with any generator?

I tried something like

```
add_definitions(-DTARGET_FILE_NAME=$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:NAME>>)
```

but even

```
add_definitions(-DTARGET_FILE_NAME=$<TARGET_PROPERTY:NAME>)
```

just places the unescaped `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:NAME> in the buildfile. I also tried with just`$`, but no luck either.

Note that the *compile* build command does not know the name of the *linker* output in many build files, so there does not seem to be any generator-specific hack for some of them either.

Answer (score 1):

`compile_definitions` does not support generator expressions. Use `target_compile_definitions`, which does:

```
target_compile_definitions(somelib PRIVATE NAME=$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:somelib>)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_compile_definitions.html

Comment: Now if I could somehow say that all targets should get the definition (with respective file name). There is many of them.